# connect functional component to redux store

Tags: reactjs

I'm modernising a react application that I'm working on and I started to use hooks.

Before the component I had was the classic class component, with the constructor, state and everything. I was hooking it to redux the following way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

import Logs from "NS/src/Screen/Logs"

import store from 'NS/src/Reducers/store'

const LogsStore = connect(state => ({ store: state.store }))(Logs);
```

Now I'm following a tutorial on Hooks, so I change my component accordingly:

```
export default function Logs() {
  const {status, filteredStatus} = this.props.store
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState('')

  clearLogs = () => {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

the problem is that now `this` is undefined. How can I access the store from this kind of component?

Comment: `export default function Logs(props) { ...// props.store }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is undefined because functional components do not have an instance, the redux props are available at `props` which is a regular object

```
const mapState = state => ({ foo : state.foo })

const Component = connect(mapState)(props =>{
    console.log(props.foo)
})
```

Comment: The solution which you offered is working for me as well, I am getting redux props but not getting the normal props that I pass to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Props are passed as an argument to your functional component:

```
export default function Logs(props) {
  const {status, filteredStatus} = props.store
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState('')

  clearLogs = () => {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

...and if you're into saving lines:

```
export default function Logs({ store: { status, filteredStatus } }) {
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState('')

  clearLogs = () => {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```